# Index out of Range Microsoft Access Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, windows-forms-designer, indexoutofrangeexception

I am creating a Windows Form Application with C# and am connecting to a Microsoft Access Database. My issue is that when I create a new record I have the window close and then open a different window where I then load the newly created record in my database. However I am constantly getting an Index Out of Range error because it appears that the record is not created in the database in time for the second query to retrieve it.

I know the record is created it just will not be created in time for the second query to retrieve it.

Can anyone help? I will post my code below:

```
  conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter da =
                       new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                OleDbCommandBuilder cmdB =
                       new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
                da.MissingSchemaAction =
                       MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;


                da.Fill(ds, tableName);

                //-------- Update the first Row ---
                DataRow row = ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].NewRow();
                row["FirstName"] = textBox1.Text;
                row["LastName"] = textBox2.Text;
                row["EmailAddress"] = textBox3.Text;
                row["GuestStreet"] = textBox4.Text;
                row["GuestCity"] = textBox5.Text;
                row["GuestZip"] = textBox6.Text;
                row["CreditCard"] = textBox7.Text;
                row["ExpDate"] = textBox8.Text;
                row["CVVNumber"] = textBox9.Text;
                row["NumOfGuests"] = numericUpDown1.Value;
                row["CheckInDate"] = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                row["CheckOutDate"] = dateTimePicker2.Value;
                row["SpecialRequests"] = textBox10.Text;
                row["CheckedIn"] = false;
                row["CurrentReservation"] = true;
                ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows.Add(row);
                da.Update(ds, "ReservationDatabase");
```

This is where I create the record

```
String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Cody Richard\Desktop\Software Engineering\Front Desk Prototype\Reservations.accdb";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        String tableName = "ReservationDatabase";
        string SqlString = String.Format("SELECT LastName, ID, CheckInDate FROM ReservationDatabase WHERE (CurrentReservation=true);");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlString, conn);
            da.Fill(ds, tableName);
            label5.Text = ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows[1]["ID"].ToString();
            ReservationID = int.Parse(ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows[1]["ID"].ToString());
           label6.Text = ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows[1]["LastName"].ToString();
           label7.Text = ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows[1]["CheckInDate"].ToString();
```

This is the code where I call that record with a query and set it equal to labels on the windows form.

Let me know if you would like to see anything else. Thank you!

Comment: You may need to use `WHERE (CurrentReservation= -1)` instead of `true`.

Comment: This code works. When I have multiple reservations added into the database and call the query I can change the State of CurrentReservation from true to false. The issue is when I have 1 row in the query it throws an indexoutofrange issue. Thank you for the tip though I appreciate it

Comment: Is the error thrown when accessing `ds.Tables["ReservationDatabase"].Rows[1]["ID"]` ? I would assume that the first (and only) row of `ds` has the index 0, not 1.

Comment: That is exactly when the error is thrown....I have a holder record that holds the 0 index of the query. When I delete the holder it still gives me the same error however this time it tells me there is no record at index 0

Comment: So you are 100% sure that `"SELECT LastName, ID, CheckInDate FROM ReservationDatabase WHERE (CurrentReservation=true);"` returns at least 2 records? Try also executing this directly in Access, if possible.

Comment: Yea i am sure that the query returns 2 records or 1 depending on what index I am using. I have tested the query in Access and it worked